# How can I convert NetCDF files to CSV on Chromebook

Tags: csv, netcdf, chromebook

I am constrined to using Chromebooks atm

I want to start using some datasets (latest HadCRUT4 monthly temperature average data series) but I can only find NetCDF downloads.

Is it possible to convert NetCDF to CSV on a Chromebook

Is there a ready-converted copy of the dataset available for download that I have not found?

Answer (score 0):

In python, using the package `xarray`, you can read netcdf files, transform them to pandas DataFrrames using the `.to_dataframe` method, and the saving it into a csv file. However, beware of the structure : through these transformations, the data is flattened, the coordinates are repeated numerous times, thus losing the interest of the netcdf format.

```
import xarray as xr

path_nc_file = '/folder/file.nc'

xr.open_dataset(path_nc_file ).to_dataframe().to_csv('path/export/file.csv')
```